# do_shortcode() doesn't work if shortcode contained in variable, works if shortcode passed as string

Tags: plugins, templates, shortcode

I'm developing a plugin, wherein one of the features is to switch out forms on a specific page by changing the shortcode within a custom field.

within my plugin file:

```
function getShort()
{
    global $post;
    $m = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short', true);
    return $m;
}
```

within my theme file:

```
$short = getShort();
echo do_shortcode($short);
```

With the code above, it just prints out the shortcode. If I echo the value of $short, copy and paste that as the argument for do_shortcode(), it prints out the expected value.

I am 100% confident that the value of $short is a string, and is the correctly formatted shortcode. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: have you tried to add `esc_attr` to `$m`, like `return esc_attr( $m );`?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the string in `$short` variable is between square brakets, like `[header]`. If it's not stored that way, make the call like this `echo do_shortcode('['.$short.']');`

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're confident that this isn't the case, it sounds as if the value you are passing manually is not the same as the value in `$short`.

Dump the contents of `$short` (`var_dump($short);`) and have a look the **source** of the genereated page! There's a good chance that the variable contains tags or other chars that won't be visible in the rendered browser view.

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($varName); exit;` will make it easily visible on the page.